# Looping through a CSV and printing to a new CSV

Tags: php, csv

I am reading information from a csv, making some changes to it and writing it to a new CSV.  I would like to be able to check the value of a field ($row[14])before it moves on to the next row.  If the value is the same as the one before, then I would like it to add the values of that row to the current row.

Here is my PHP

```
$file = fopen("tesy-3.csv","r");

if ($file) {
    $fp = fopen('mailchimp.csv', 'w');  

    while  ( $row = fgetcsv( $file, ";" ) ) { 

        if ($email = $row[14] == $email) {

            array_push($data, $row[2], 
                $row[3], 
                $row[14], 
                $row[6] . ' ' . $row[7] . ' ' . $row[8], 
                $row[11] . ' ' . $row[10] . ', ' . $row[12], 
                jdtogregorian ( jewishtojd($Hebmonth, $row[6], 5774 ))
                );
        } else { 
            $data = array ( $row[2], 
                $row[3], 
                $row[14], 
                $row[6] . ' ' . $row[7] . ' ' . $row[8], 
                $row[11] . ' ' . $row[10] . ', ' . $row[12], 
                jdtogregorian ( jewishtojd($Hebmonth, $row[6], 5774 ))
              );

        }   


        $email = $row[14];

        fputcsv($fp, $data);
     }

 }

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: What fields are you talking about ADDING? if you get 2 consecutive rows where row[14] is that same. Some idea about the data might also be useful

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do such processing, reading and writing per line seems problematic.

Instead, parse the whole file in memory. (I hope is not too big; if it is too big, this will cause problems).

In this example, I'm assuming that the field you want to verify is the number 1, and the field you are going to sum is the number 3.

So, if we take this csv: (notice how the first 2 lines have the same `no` value at field 1)

```
io;no;pat;10
su;no;ret;12
se;mi;sol;15
```

And use this code:

```
<?php

$file = explode("\n", file_get_contents("tesy-3.csv"));
$output = fopen('mailchimp.csv', 'w');

$csv = array_map(function ($x) { return str_getcsv($x, ';'); }, $file);


$result = array_reduce($csv, function ($a, $b) {
  // $values is an array containing only the field 1 of each line.
  $values = array_map(function ($x) { return $x[1]; }, $a);

  if (isset($b[1])) {
    // Check if the current field 1 already is set in a previous line
    $key = array_search($b[1], $values);

    if ($key !== false) {
      // The field is already set, so we do the sum
      $a[$key][3] += $b[3];
    } else {
      // Is not set, so we just push the line
      array_push($a, $b);
    }
  }

  return $a;
}, Array());

foreach($result as $line) {
  fputcsv($output, $line);
}

fclose($output)
```

The output is this:

```
io,no,pat,22
se,mi,sol,15
```

The result has the values of the field number 3 summed. (10 + 12)

Comment: Well if you dont know if it is not to big its a bit dumb suggesting a major change that will mess them up just because you have some code that has nothing to do with his question you want to paste into an answer.

Comment: its actually a pretty large file 6000+ rows.  I just modified my code and it almost doing what I'd like it to, except that it writes the row with the same value each time that it adds more on.  How can I modify this so that it only writes it once and adds on the duplicated values.

Comment: Oh, my bad for not asking first how long the file was. But, no, this wasn't some code that I wanted to paste. But yeah, I should have asked  first.

Comment: Having said that, if the rows with the same field are indeed consecutive, I think it should be quite possible to change the OP code to do the job. But if the rows are *not* necessarily consecutive and instead they could be in any order, I think it would be necessary to keep the whole file in memory. Which in such case I think my solution is acceptable. But perhaps I'm terrible wrong XD. What you think?

Comment: I did an ORDER BY before exporting the CSV. So they are consecutive.  I edited the code about.  Do you know how I can have the rows that are having values added on only print once?